# How to add multiple products to cart magento 2

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, extensions, simple-product, grouped-products

I have a problem in magento 2, I wish to customize the product details page for adding multiple proucts to cart, which means "product-options-wrapper" div(configurable.phtml) along with option to add quantity(addtocart.phtml) should be generate dynamically on add new item button click. is it possible using custom module ?
[image]

Comment: https://marketplace.magento.com/eecom-ajaxaddmultiple.html
>>This plugin on market place can help you out

Comment: @krishnakumarC i've created like this one before but in magento 1, basically i need to modify the product page to create form like above, and the action of the form will go to custom module controller which will process the entire input and add it to cart programmatically

Answer (score 0):

As I can see from your image, you may want your configurable products to be displayed in a table or in grid but it seems that customers still have to choose custom options from the drop-down list.

Then I search " display configurable products in the table or grid in Magento 2" on Google and see that there are some extensions that can handle this kind of display simply.

I select the following module from a Magento provider to check in more details:

http://bsscommerce.com/magento-configurable-product-grid-table-view-for-magento-2.html

It shows all simple products in the table without selecting custom options from the drop-down list as your description. However, I find it convenient to display configurable products because customers can directly see all simple products made of attributes and also they can choose quantities to add multiple products to cart by clicking to Add to Cart button.